# Rabbitmq primary node rejoining a cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, failover

I have a cluster of 3 rabbitmq nodes spread out on 3 different servers. The second and third node joins the first node and forms the cluster. In the process of testing for failover I am finding that once the primary node is killed, I am not able to make it rejoin the cluster.  The documentation does not state that I have to use join_cluster or any other command, after startup.  I tried join_cluster but it is rejected since the cluster with name is the same as the node host. Is there a way to make this work?

cluster_status displays the following (not from the primary node):

```
Cluster status of node 'rabbit@<secondary>' ...
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@<primary>','rabbit@<secondary>',
                'rabbit@<tertiary>']}]},
 {running_nodes,['rabbit@<secondary>','rabbit@<tertiary>']},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@<primary>">>},
 {partitions,[]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

On one of the nodes which are in the cluster, use the command

```
rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@rabbitmq1
```

To make the current cluster forget the old primary.
Now you should be able to rejoin the cluster on the old primary (rabbitmq1)

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbitmq2
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

See the [reference cluster guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html)

Answer (score 0):

A quote from [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html)

> Nodes that have been joined to a cluster can be stopped at any time.
>   It is also ok for them to crash. In both cases the rest of the cluster
>   continues operating unaffected, and the nodes automatically "catch up"
>   with the other cluster nodes when they start up again.

So you just need to start the node that you killed/stopped. Doesn't make a difference if it's "primary" or not - if it was primary and then killed, some other node becomes the primary one.

I've just tested this (with docker of course) and works as expected.

Comment: Doesn't for me.  As shown in the above message.  It does not show the primary node as running.